# KDE dynamic high-dpi text scaling

Tags: x11, gnome, kde, dpi, high-dpi

I am looking for an equivalent of the following gnome setup, in KDE:

Under **gnome+X11**, I can get instant scaling of gnome apps, KDE apps and chrome/chromium (>v49) when plugging my high-dpi monitor (27" 4K) by running:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.4
```

Note that (in a neophyte's words) this is not doing framebuffer-level scaling (that would be gnome's scaling-factor), it' only telling the toolkits to use bigger fonts (images are not affected).

This gets picked-up **instantly** by gnome, qt, chrome. Other aps, like Intellij IDEs or Firefox need a restart (for Firefox I could script in a change of `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`).

On the other hand, in **KDE**, both Plasma "*Displays - Scale Display*" and "*Fonts - Force fonts DPI*" settings require a restart of all apps **including the same KDE apps which autodetected the gnome scaling change**!!

This may be due to the KDE-GTK theme picking up the gnome setting, but still, it means Qt *can* redraw the interface in response to the change.

Am I overlooking something? Can I modify the same low-level setting underlying the gnome one, from KDE? Is there something that can be improved in KDE code to improve the situation?

I ran through [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI) and [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/MonitorDPI) doc without success.

Comment: Are you using KDE with X11 or wayland?

Comment: I tested under x11 since it's fedora's default (and kde-wayland is not recommended for everybody yet?) I use wmctrl, xclip etc but could switch if needed.

Comment: I am not sure how you can get what you want from KDE + X11 but I believe that the scaling is immediate in KDE with Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

Running `kwin --replace &` in a terminal seems to help at least with newly started applications.

In addition one can throw in a:

```
kquitapp5 plasmashell
kstart5 plasmashell
```

Ideas from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/878023/how-do-i-change-display-scaling-dynamically